# How to get value from Json file

Tags: java, android, json, api, gson

I am retrieving an Json from an API. The problem is that I don't have any idea on how to convert Json format to a format maybe a java class so that it can be used by me to get the intended values.

This is my sample Json format

```
{
"par_a":".....",
"par_b": [ {
"b1":".....",
"b2":".....",
"b3":".....",
"b4":".....",
"b5":".....",
"b6":".....",
"b7":".....",
"b8":".....",
"b9":".....",
"b10": { "b10-1":".....", "b10-2":".....", "b10-3":"....." } ,
"b11": { "b11-1": ["....." ], "b11-2": ["....." ] } , 
"b13":"......."
} ] 
}
```

I do not have an option to contact the owner of the API and understand how this works and hence any help would be really grateful.

I have seen many posts online but I have nowhere seen a Json format as mine hence no solution has worked for me.

Comment: which value do you need?

Comment: @GourangoSutradhar Thanks for the reply. I need to get all the values as they will be used by me at some point of time if not altogether. If possible getting them in a structured way such as a  java class will be more better.

Comment: Have you tried using DTO generator? With DTO you can convert a json to Gson class . So that you can get the attributes directly from that class.

Comment: @PoojaRajendranC Thanks for the comment. Have replied to your answer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Suppose you are trying to find the string value for `b10-1` :

The code will be like below:

```
String json = "{par_a:.....,par_b: [ {b1:.....,b2:.....,b3:.....,b4:.....,b5:.....,b6:.....,b7:.....,b8:.....,b9:.....,b10: { b10-1:....., b10-2:....., b10-3:..... } ,b11: { b11-1: [..... ], b11-2: [..... ] } , b13:.......} ]}";

try{
    String result = new JSONObject(json).getJSONArray("par_b").getJSONObject(0).getJSONObject("b_10").getString("b10-1");
}catch(Exception e){

}
```

Comment: The answer is totally hardcoded. It will break, when the JSON changes, also the parsing of objects is vague and unclear.

Comment: Yes I know. But he is too new to having clear understand about the json. So I have hardcoded it as he can understand what is happening. and know something abour jsonarray and jsobobject

Comment: @ShamsulArefinSajib Thnak You very much for the answer. Your answer was THE ONLY ANSWER WHICH HELPED ME TO UNDERSTAND THE JSON CONCEPT. Please ignore the other comments. Fantastic answer. Thanks once again.

Comment: Can You please help me also to get the b11-1 object. I think b11-1 is an array. please correct if I am wrong.

Comment: Yes     `b11-1` is an array. replace the `getJSONObject("b_10")` by `getJsonArray("b_11"')` and then get the object from the array. **You are most welcome :)**

Answer (score 1):

A nice workaround would be to create a Model corresponding to the response you're receiving from the server and using [GSON](https://github.com/google/gson) library you can easily deserialize the json to your model.
Your model will be something like this:

```
public class MyResponseModel {

    @SerializedName("par_a")
    private String parameterA;
    @SerializedName("par_b")
    private List<AnotherModel> parametersB;
    /.../
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Request you to please provide further details as a new developer like me will not be able to understand on how to use the GSON library in detail. The other answer was useful to me to understand the concept of JSON and how to convert them.Thanks Anyway.

Comment: importing GSON to your project is as easy as pasting this in your gradle file:
`dependencies {
  implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
}`

Comment: and here is a very helpful tutorial for using Gson:
https://futurestud.io/tutorials/gson-getting-started-with-java-json-serialization-deserialization

Answer (score 1):

> If you get the data from your json file and it store in your project then
>   **your solution is here.**

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
        String customRatioResponse = LocalUtils.loadJSONFromAsset(getActivity(), "custom_ratio.json"); // here custom_ratio.json is my json file. it's store in assets folder of project
        CustomRatioList getSampleImageResponse = gson.fromJson(customRatioResponse, CustomRatioList.class); // here CustormRatioList is my POJO file
        Log.i(TAG, "getAllCategory() -> Offline list size: " + (getSampleImageResponse.getCustomRatio() != null ? getSampleImageResponse.getCustomRatio().size() : 0));
        return getSampleImageResponse.getCustomRatio();
```

Here, If your Json file having too much data or list of data then it gives you arrayList type of data.

**LocalUtils.java**

```
public class LocalUtils {

    public static String loadJSONFromAsset(Context context, String jsonFilePath) {
        String json = null;
        try {
            InputStream is = context.getAssets().open(jsonFilePath);
            int size = is.available();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
            is.read(buffer);
            is.close();
            json = new String(buffer, "UTF-8");
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "";
        }
        return json;
    }
}
```

If will you get pojo of your json then go to http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/  paste your sample data json and get pojo structure. Thank you for read.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But your answer helps to load the file from asset. But my Json file/string is from an API. Also I was searching to get/read the values in each parameter. Thanks Anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You have an excellent library doing that, Use GSON lib. You just have to create an object representing your Json File, and when you will decode it, it will feel your object with your json datas !

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am aware of the GSON library but don't know how it is used. Anyway Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use this way

```
    public String loadJSONFromAsset() {
    String json = null;
    try {
        InputStream is = getActivity().getAssets().open("filename.json");
        int size = is.available();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
        is.read(buffer);
        is.close();
        json = new String(buffer, "UTF-8");
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
    return json;
}
```

and then parse the json

```
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(loadJSONFromAsset());
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But your answer helps to load the file from asset. But my Json file/string is from an API. Also I was searching to get/read the values in each parameter. Thanks Anyway.

Answer (score 1):

1. Install DTO generator plug in for android studio ("this will be useful for future works too"). : File -> settings -> plugins -> search for DTO and install
2. Create a simple class say DataRetriever. Place cursor in that class and press Alt+insert -> select DTO from JSON
3. Enter obtained JSON in the window and press generate. This will make your class Gson with all attributes in Json. Create getter and setter for attributes. Result will be like

   ```
   public class DataRetriever {

   @Expose
   @SerializedName("par_b")
   private List<Par_bEntity> mPar_b;
   @Expose
   @SerializedName("par_a")
   private String mPar_a;

   public List<Par_bEntity> getmPar_b() {
   return mPar_b;
   }

   public void setmPar_b(List<Par_bEntity> mPar_b) {
   this.mPar_b = mPar_b;
   }

   public String getmPar_a() {
   return mPar_a;
   }

   public void setmPar_a(String mPar_a) {
   this.mPar_a = mPar_a;
   }
   /**
    * Similar to these getter and setter, you can add getter and setter for sub 
    classes also
    */
     }

     class Par_bEntity {

      @Expose
   @SerializedName("b13")
   private String mB13;
   @Expose
   @SerializedName("b11")
   private B11Entity mB11;
   @Expose
   @SerializedName("b10")
   private B10Entity mB10;
   @Expose
   @SerializedName("b9")
   private String mB9;
   @Expose
   @SerializedName("b8")
   private String mB8;
   @Expose
   @SerializedName("b7")
   private String mB7;
   @Expose
   @SerializedName("b6")
    private String mB6;
   @Expose
   @SerializedName("b5")
   private String mB5;
   @Expose
   @SerializedName("b4")
   private String mB4;
   @Expose
   @SerializedName("b3")
   private String mB3;
   @Expose
   @SerializedName("b2")
   private String mB2;
   @Expose
   @SerializedName("b1")
   private String mB1;
   }

   class B10Entity {
      @Expose
     @SerializedName("b10-3")
    private String b10_3;
    @Expose
    @SerializedName("b10-2")
    private String b10_2;
     @Expose
    @SerializedName("b10-1")
     private String b10_1;
     }

     class B11Entity {
    @Expose
    @SerializedName("b11-2")
    private List<String> b11_2;
    @Expose
    @SerializedName("b11-1")
    private List<String> b11_1;
   }
   ```
4. At the place where you obtain json string get values to DataRetriever class by calling

   ```
   DataRetriever mDataRetriever = new Gson().fromJson(jsonString, DataRetriever.class);
   ```

   Using mDataRetriever object and getter methods you can retrieve value using

   ```
   Ex : mDataRetriever.getmPar_a()for value “par_a”
   ```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But somehow I was not able to install the plugin. Tried it twice but both the time it was installed but when restarting Android Studio it was some how being uninstalled. Thanks Anyway.